# How do I know if platform projects also require a NuGet package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

In my solution I have a PCL project and two other projects, each for different platforms.

Sometimes a NuGet package used in PCL require installing it to the platform project as well, otherwise things will crash at runtime.

When I install the NuGet package, how do if it's also required to install it to the platform projects?

For example, it's not clear to me if Microsoft.Net.Http requires also installation in Xamarin Android project or not. This is just an example.

Or, I don't know if SQLite.Net-PCL requires it to be installed on platform projects as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you can do:

- Read the documentation provided by the NuGet package author. Either from a project web site or in the description for the NuGet package.
- Use your favourite search engine for examples of how to use that NuGet package.
- If there are multiple NuGet packages that are named after the platform then that gives you an idea that the PCL NuGet package might not work in the platform specific project.
- Have a look inside the NuGet package using something like the NuGet Package Explorer available on Windows. If the NuGet package has lib directories that are platform specific as well as a PCL directory then it will need to be installed in the platform specific project.
- Run your application and see if it works.

Taking Microsoft.Net.Http as an example. The documentation does not really say explicitly. If you search the internet you can find a blog post or two that mentions that you have to install it into your platform specific project.

If you take a look inside the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package you can see it has several lib directories:

[image: Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet Lib directories]

There are platform specific directories, such as MonoAndroid and Xamarin.iOS10 as well as PCL directories, such as portable-net45+win8. This suggests you should install it into all your projects.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I wish it was easier. Probably NuGet package authors should be more clear about it in the description.

Comment: Matt, I don't think looking inside the package for lib directories is a good indication. I'm not sure but I think sometimes authors just recompile for the code for different targets, even if the PCL could be enough.

Comment: I think looking inside the NuGet package for lib directories does give you an indication of what platforms the package author has decided to support. This is basically what NuGet looks at to see if you can use a NuGet package in a project. If there are only PCLs then it also implicitly supports other platforms that may not have an explicit lib directory. Typically you do not recompile the code for a particular platform unless you have platform specific code.